# Extraneous schema tags in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I have written a Sparql query.

```
PREFIX table:<http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable#>
SELECT ?name ?color
FROM <PeriodicTable.owl>
WHERE
{ ?element table:group ?group.
  ?group table:name "Noble Gas".
  ?element table:name ?name.
  ?element table:color ?color.
}
```

I am getting the output with schema tags attached to it as below:

```
| "chlorine"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>    | "green"^^<again link>
```

and so on...                      |

Why does this happen, and how should I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the RDF data you are querying there are typed literals, a typed literal as the name suggests is a literal associated with a datatype.

RDF and SPARQL defers to [XML Schema Datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) for common data types hence why you see these particular URIS in the output.

You can have the SPARQL engine strip the datatypes off the values using the `STR()` function like so:

```
PREFIX table:<http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable#>

SELECT (STR(?name) AS ?NameString) (STR(?color) AS ?ColourString)
FROM <PeriodicTable.owl>
WHERE
{ 
  ?element table:group ?group.
  ?group table:name "Noble Gas".
  ?element table:name ?name.
  ?element table:color ?color.
}
```

This requires a SPARQL engine that supports SPARQL 1.1 since this uses the [SELECT Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#selectExpressions) feature, most SPARQL engines these days will support this.